# How to set up an alarm that particularly monitors throttling (429 - Too Many Requests) of an AWS API Gateway API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, throttling

One way is to make the alarm monitor the auto-emitted Cloudwatch metric `4XXError`. However, the problem with that is that it would not distinguish throttling errors (`429`) from other `4xx` errors. So my alarm may be triggered for reasons other than throttling, which goes against the particular purpose of the alarm - to specifically monitor throttling only.

Answer (score 2):

Api Gateway Logs, as long as they are enabled at stage level, should print a log similar to

> *******vit5mg exceeded quota limit for API Stage abc123npx8/qa: Key quota exhausted for Usage Plan ID v2tyvt. Limit: 1 Period: DAY Method
>
> completed with status: 429

We can have a cloudwatch logs Metric filter on text `completed with status: 429` with metric value 1. And we can create a dashboard or an alarm on it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is now possible to set it up with the right configuration:

1. use the right settings for api access logging as per the image enclosed:
   [image: aws api, logging levels]
2. for the log format, include the following JSON (some fields are excessive, make sure they match your needs, StatusCode will provide you the required 429 response in case of throttling)

```
{"APIId":"$context.apiId","DomainName":"$context.domainName","ErrResponse":"$context.error.responseType","ErrValidString":"$context.error.validationErrorString","ErrorMessg":"$context.error.message","RequestId":"$context.requestId","RequestPath":"$context.path","RequestTime":"$context.requestTime","ResourcePath":"$context.resourcePath","SourceIp":"$context.identity.sourceIp","Stage":"$context.stage", "StatusCode":"$context.status"}
```

3. Set up a metric filter with the right json pattern, e.g. { $.StatusCode = 429 }
4. Set up an alarm based on the filter

and voila !